# How to iterate backward with a `for` loop on an array of characters

Tags: c++

Im trying to output only the char `l`, `u`, `c`, `k`, but I can't end the loop.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char msg[]={'k','c','u','l',' ','d','o','o','g'};
    for (int i = 3; i < 4; i--)
        cout << msg[i];
}
```

Comment: `i++` instead of `i-- `? or `i != -1` instead of `i < 4`?

Comment: When you begin with `i` set to 3, how many times do you expect to ***decrement it*** before it becomes 4?

Comment: You want a condition that stops being true when you want the loop to end, e.g. `i>=0`.

Comment: You can use `i < 4` as the condition (there are better ways of going about this though), but use some unsigned value i,e, `size_t`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for (int i = 3; i >= 0; i--)
   cout << msg[i];
```

Comment: Wouldn't `auto` detect `size_t`, meaning that the condition is always true?

Comment: sorry, of course you're right :D

Comment: That would print all the letters, which is not the problem at hand.

Answer (score 1):

As you are running backwards, you should overthink your condition.

Right now your are running as long as i is smaller than 4, which is always true.

try this instead:

```
for (int i=3;i>=0;i--)
```